# back button not calling onPause

Tags: android

I have an activity that displays sensor values and sends them to a synchronous queue, from the `onSensorChanged` method. I have a timeout on the publish to queue so that the `onSensorChanged` method does not block, when the queue is blocking. I am then expecting that the `onPause` method will be called when the back button is pressed, however it is not and the screen just hangs without returning to the previous screen. Any idea why this is happening?

Btw, when the queue does not block (data is removed by the subscriber) then all works as expected, `onPause` is called when the back button is pressed.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    TextView tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRemLinAccX);
    TextView tvY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRemLinAccY);
    TextView tvZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRemLinAccZ);
    String x = String.format(format, event.values[0]);
    String y = String.format(format, event.values[1]);
    String z = String.format(format, event.values[2]);
    tvX.setText(x);
    tvY.setText(y);
    tvZ.setText(z);

    try {
        if (btConnection.isRunning()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ queue values");
            queue.offer(constructData(x, y, z), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "+++  err " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: A/ you are blocking the ui thread or B/ you are overriding onBackPressed or onKeyEvent

Comment: I am not overriding onBackPressed or onKeyEvent. And I do not think I am blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are blocking the UI with other operations (when you execute something on the main thread), then the back button will not work, you should do any operation that takes time on a background thread.

Comment: I do not think I am blocking the UI thread as the queue.offer times out if the message is not published to the queue.

Comment: how is that implemented? The only reason for the back button not to respond is because the UI thread is blocked.

Comment: what is the queue object? what does the method constructData do? Post this methods

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be resolved though I am not quite sure how I did it, so have included the code for others to use. I did  a lot of restructuring to ensure that connection resources were cleaned up properly and now the onPause, and onDestroy, methods are called when the back button is pressed.

Fyi, this activity opens a bluetooth connection and sends sensor data to another computer to be used to control a LEGO NXT robot.

```
package uk.co.moonsit.apps.sensors.remote;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import uk.co.moonsit.apps.sensors.R;
import uk.co.moonsit.bluetooth.BluetoothConnection;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RemoteLinearAccelerationActivity extends Activity implements
        SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "RemoteLinearAccelerationActivity";

    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mLinAcc;
    private String format = "%.3f";
    private String type;
    private BluetoothConnection btConnection;
    private String delimiter = "|";
    private String cr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_remote_linear_acceleration);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        byte[] crb = new byte[1];
        crb[0] = 13;
        cr = new String(crb);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mLinAcc = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
        queue = new SynchronousQueue<String>();
        type = "LinAcc";
        btConnection = new BluetoothConnection(queue, "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB", "<MAC address here>", "11", "28,13");
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ onCreate ");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.remote_linear_acceleration, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        TextView tvX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRemLinAccX);
        TextView tvY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRemLinAccY);
        TextView tvZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRemLinAccZ);
        String x = String.format(format, event.values[0]);
        String y = String.format(format, event.values[1]);
        String z = String.format(format, event.values[2]);
        tvX.setText(x);
        tvY.setText(y);
        tvZ.setText(z);

        try {
            String msg = constructData(x, y, z);
            if (btConnection.isRunning()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "+++ queue values");
                queue.offer(msg, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "+++  err " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    private String constructData(String x, String y, String z) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(type + delimiter);
        sb.append(x + delimiter);
        sb.append(y + delimiter);
        sb.append(z);
        sb.append(cr);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ onPause unregisterListener ");
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ onResume registerListener ");
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLinAcc, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ onResume start btConnection");
        new Thread(btConnection).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ onDestroy closing btConnection");
        btConnection.stop();
    }

}



package uk.co.moonsit.bluetooth;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import uk.co.moonsit.messaging.BeginEndEnvelope;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
//import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.util.Log;

public class BluetoothConnection implements Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnection";

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket clientSocket;
    private DataInputStream in = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;
    private String address;
    private boolean isConnected = false;
    private BeginEndEnvelope envelope;
    private String uuid;
    private boolean isRunning = true;

    public BluetoothConnection(BlockingQueue<String> q, String ud, String a,
            String start, String end) {
        uuid = ud;
        queue = q;
        address = a;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        envelope = new BeginEndEnvelope(start, end);
    }

    private void getDevice() throws IOException {
        device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    }

    private void getSocket() throws IOException {
        clientSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(uuid));
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    private boolean connect() {

        if (!isConnected) {
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ connecting");
            try {
                getSocket();

                Log.i(TAG, "+++ b4 connect");
                clientSocket.connect();
                Log.i(TAG, "+++ connected");

                isConnected = true;

                in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                Log.i(TAG, "+++ streams created");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Long sleep = (long) 10000;
                Log.e(TAG, "+++ connection failed, sleep for " + sleep);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return isConnected;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            getDevice();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "+++  device error " + e.toString());
        }
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                processData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "+++  data error " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        close();
        Log.i(TAG, "+++  ending bluetooth run");
    }

    private void closeSocket() {
        if (clientSocket != null)
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "+++  socket closed");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void closeStreams() {
        if (in != null)
            try {
                in.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "+++  input stream closed");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "+++  input stream not closed " + e.toString());
            }

        if (out != null)
            try {
                out.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "+++  output stream closed");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "+++  output stream not closed " + e.toString());
            }
    }

    private void close() {
        closeStreams();
        closeSocket();

        isConnected = false;
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }

    private void processData() throws Exception {

        try {

            String outData = null;
            int timer = 0;
            while (outData == null) {
                if (!connect())
                    return;
                Log.i(TAG, "+++ waiting on queue ");
                outData = queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// .take();
                if (timer++ > 15) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            envelope.sendMessage(outData, out);
            String inData = envelope.receiveMessage(in);
            Log.i(TAG, "+++ response " + inData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "+++ processData error " + e.toString());
            close();
            throw e;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Correction, this code did not resolve the issue, but I think I have figured out the problem. Which was that whatever is calling onSensorChanged is queueing the events. So my queue was slowing down the UI thread which meant that there were lots of calls to onSensorChanged to catch up with the events. This meant that the UI thread was falling far behind and became unresponsive. I have resolved this issue by replacing SynchronousQueue with LinkedList which doesn't wait on the other end of the queue, and I will let the other end (a non-UI thread) deal with the rate of processing issue.

Comment: Hey @PerceptualRobotics - Facing the same issue in 2019. My app's buttons become unresponsive after about 10 seconds of the app running which also causes the onPause method to not run and subsequently all of my background threads are not safely exited. I am using onSensorChanged for the magnetometer. Are you able to post an example to demonstrate how the issue was overcome?